Failed to connect to 18x.130.1x5.xxx port 10000: Connection timed out
I opened vps from azure ubuntu 20.04 and installed cyberpanel here, then I opened all incoming and outgoing ports in azure, I installed script, this script sends curl with proxy but I get error "Curl Hatası [Kod: https://xxxwebsite.com/ ]: Failed to connect to 18x.130.1x5.xx port 10000: Connection timed out" how can I solve this error?

I turned off the firewall and changed the ssl certificate but it didn't work, I also tried to solve the problem with chatgpt but it didn't work
